# Why does runtime shiny in R markdown ot show ggplot stat_summary geom with text correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, yaml, r-markdown

I'm getting different plot results between a plot in an simple Rmarkdown HTML doc and the same plot produced in an RShiny equivalent, i.e. by adding adding **runtime: shiny** to the yaml header.

Below is the code for each version (but the only difference is one line in the yaml header) and the resulting image

#### Result when running as Rmarkdown doc:

````
---
title: "test"
date: "2023-08-08"
output:
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE)
library(readr);library(dplyr);library(magrittr); library(ggplot2);
library(tibble);
```

```{r}

set.seed(1)
data_df <- bind_rows(tibble(type = "type A", y = rnorm(150, 10, 1)),
                    tibble(type = "type B", y = rnorm(100, 5, 1)))
data_df$type <- factor(data_df$type)
n_mean_fun <- function(x) {
  return(data.frame(y = mean(x),
                    label = paste0("mean = ", round(mean(x),2), "\n",
                                   "n = ", length(x))
                    ))
}
ggplot(data_df, 
       aes(x = type, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
stat_summary(fun.data = "n_mean_fun", geom = "text", 
             color = "black")

```
````

Plot when running as Rmarkdown html output:
[image: Plot when running as Rmarkdown html output]

#### Result when running as Rshiny doc:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Ronan Brady"
date: "2023-08-08"
output:
  html_document: default
runtime: shiny 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE)
library(readr);library(dplyr);library(magrittr); library(ggplot2);
library(tibble);
```

```{r}

set.seed(1)
data_df <- bind_rows(tibble(type = "type A", y = rnorm(150, 10, 1)),
                    tibble(type = "type B", y = rnorm(100, 5, 1)))
data_df$type <- factor(data_df$type)
n_mean_fun <- function(x) {
  return(data.frame(y = mean(x),
                    label = paste0("mean = ", round(mean(x),2), "\n",
                                   "n = ", length(x))
                    ))
}
ggplot(data_df, 
       aes(x = type, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
stat_summary(fun.data = "n_mean_fun", geom = "text", 
             color = "black")

```
````

Plot when runing as rshiny doc:
[image: Plot when runing as rshiny doc]

Can anyone help explain why this might occur and how the shiny version can be made to be consisent with the doc version as would be expected?

Thanks, R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fun.data` argument in `stat_summary()` should not be in quotes.

Here is the correct code:

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Ronan Brady"
date: "2023-08-08"
output:
  html_document: default
runtime: shiny 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(reader)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
```

```{r}

set.seed(1)
data_df <- bind_rows(tibble(type = "type A", y = rnorm(150, 10, 1)),
                    tibble(type = "type B", y = rnorm(100, 5, 1)))
data_df$type <- factor(data_df$type)
n_mean_fun <- function(x) {
  return(data.frame(y = mean(x),
                    label = paste0("mean = ", round(mean(x),2), "\n",
                                   "n = ", length(x))
                    ))
}
ggplot(data_df, 
       aes(x = type, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
stat_summary(fun.data = n_mean_fun, geom = "text", 
             color = "black")

```
````

I also moved the `library()` calls into a chunk of their own. It is not good practice to load libraries in the setup chunk. When working on an Rmd file in RStudio, the setup chunk is executed whenever you run any other chunk. Therefore the setup chunk should only include the `knitr::opts_chunk$set(...)` part.

Comment: Just a note: The issue is clearly related to running the code in a Shiny document. Actually we could pass the function name as a character string to `fun.data`, i.e. the code with quotes works fine in an R Script or in a standard Rmd. See also the examples in the docs (`?stat_summary`).